# Rails where condition on has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between product and supplier.

join table is `products_suppliers`.

I am trying to create dependent selects in a form so that when I select a supplier, in the product dropdown only corresponding products appears.

I'm having a problem with the where conditions.

If I was in a situation where product belongs_to supplier I would do:

```
 @products = Product.where("supplier_id = ?", params[:supplier_id])
```

How do I achieve the same in a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
supplier = Supplier.find_by(supplier_id: params[:supplier_id])
@products =supplier.products if supplier.present?
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have `has_and_belongs_to_many` association you can call `.products` on the `Supplier` instance.

This should do the trick

```
@products = Supplier.find(params[:supplier_id]).products
```

Comment: I get `Couldn't find Supplier with 'id'=` while I was getting a different error before so I guess your solution solves the issue. I guessthe error is related to something else in my code I'll look better into it before accepting the answer.

Comment: @Catmal sounds like `params[:supplier_id]` is returning `nil`.